# What is the best inexpensive way to bring or capture wifi signal from outside to my laptop which placed inside my house

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Outside my house there is a 2.4 GHz paid unsecured public Wi-Fi installed which I don't know where exactly it is installed. But at **Point A** I could get 3 or 4 of 4 bar of signal but at **Point B** I could only get 1 bar at night and no signal at all at noon.

Currently I positioned my laptop at **Point X** which gives me solid 2 bar at night and 1 or 2 bar at noon. But I don't like the spot because it's right under my air conditioner.

The maximum speed I could get at **Point A** is 10 Mbps, **Point B** is 2 Mbps and **Point C** is 8 Mbps.

When a Large truck passes in front of my house, my laptop suddenly lost connection for a while before regainins connection again.

Currently I have USB Wifi Adapter (TP-Link TL-WN722N) which has removable external antenna.

Is it possible to use that wifi adapter and replace the antenna with an antenna with longer cable? if not, is it possible to amplify the signal to the antenna cheaply ?

If both aren't possible what other things I can do to get the wifi signal at outside without placing my laptop at Point A and Point X ?

[image]

Comment: "I don't know exactly where it is installed".  You should install a WiFi graphing utility on your phone or tablet and walk the neighborhood, to determine where the device's signal is strongest.

Comment: iPhone doesn't support any advanced WiFi utility apps, but I've used similar app on my laptop and walk around my neighborhood and have found the router, the router is rather close, just around 15 meters away from point A, but there is a lot obscuration to router from point B, slightly less on point X, and almost nothing obscure the signal from point A.

Answer (score 3):

I’m sure there is more than one way to accomplish this task. However, based on your description, I think the best thing to do would be to purchase a directional antenna.

Directional antennas focus the signal so that the gain is significantly greater in only one direction. If you point the directional antenna at the source of the WiFi signal you will be able to get significantly better range. It will do even better if you can get the antenna up higher and achieve an unobstructed path.

There are many types of directional antenna. There are plans on the internet to even [make one out of a Pringles can.](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-make-a-wifi-antenna-out-of-a-pringles-can-nb/)

The subject of radio communications is complex and there are a lot of factors at play here. But, based on your existing situation, using a more directional antenna should easily solve your issue.

Comment: What software can I use to help me measure the signal more precisely so I can make sure I've pointed the antenna to the right direction ( Windows signal bar isn't really precise )

Comment: Anything that can display dBm in a quasi real-time experience will be good. Inssider is a good one or these alternatives https://inssider.en.softonic.com/windows/alternatives?ex=BB-682.4.

Answer (score 1):

We can't do all that much about physics.

> When a Large truck passes in front of my house, my laptop suddenly lost connection for a while before regains connection again.

There is literally a big metal thing going between you and the AP you are connected to. You can *improve* things, but that particular problem can only be really fixed by fixing the line of sight problem.

Assuming you have permission ("free" wifi can be illegal to connect to in many places), the cheapest thing to do is to get a repeater that only does 2.4 ghz. Make sure it has line of sight to wherever you're getting a connection from. These plug in, so all you need is power, and it can be connected to, say, an extension cord. I've found sometimes that moving it around helps.

You can also connect your laptop or even a router over ethernet - which means that as long as the repeater has a connection, you have the freedom to connect via a wired connection, even if the retransmitted wired connection is weak.

Comment: I don't need permission since it's a paid public wifi ( you have to pay around 4 USD/month for subscription. I think ethernet method isn't feasible since I can't find the router and if the router is accross the road, it's illegal to span your cable over public property ( road) ( though it's rarely enforced )

Comment: no no, you can put the repeater anywhere in your apartment with good signal, then connect your laptop over ethernet.

Comment: Oh thanks ,Can you give me at least one example of product like that on Amazon or other place

Comment: That's probably a question for hardware recs ;) https://www.linksys.com/sg/p/P-RE3000W/ is what I run but its pretty much a commodity bit of hardware